How to add a local package dependency to a local package in Xcode? How to nest package dependencies locally in Xcode?
I have created a local package within Xcode, with 'File -> New -> Package' and named it "BaseTypeExtension" (see image). So far so good, I can use this package in my other Xcode projects as expected (by 'File -> add Package Dependencies ... -> add Local ...').
Then I created another local package (again with 'File -> New -> Package)', but this package should depend on the first package BaseTypeExtensions. But when I try to add the dependency with 'File -> add Package Dependencies ...' surprisingly the option 'add Local ...' is not available anymore.
Can somebody help?
I want to implement such a nested package dependency but only locally (a remote repository e.g. on GitHub makes no sense to me at this moment, I don't want to share code with others, I just want to locally modularize my code using Swift Package Manager.
Any hint, workaround, link, ... is appreciated. Thanks in advance.


I too would like to know why the "Add Local" button isn't available in this situation :(

Well it turned out, you can not add package decency to an existing package with this method (add package dependency, ....), instead you have to edit your package description for the second package and enter the dependency there (see accepted answer). But we all could hope, that Apples Xcode team would find a way in the future to make this common feature easier to implement.

Well, I finally found a solution for nested local packages. Interesting though, I got more help from ChatGPT, than from here.
But the real help came from this site: https://theswiftdev.com/the-swift-package-manifest-file/
Thanks to Tibor Bödecs, who shared his knowledge about package dependencies. The key was this line of code unter the comment
// ... dependency must also be handled here on target level //
I hope it helps somebody with the same issues.
// swift-tools-version: 5.10
import PackageDescription

// Sample for dependency on other local package
let package = Package(
    name: "SecondPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SecondPackage",
            targets: ["SecondPackage"]
        ),
    ],
    // relative path to first package
    dependencies: [.package(path: "../BaseTypeExtension"),],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SecondPackage",
            // ... dependency must also be handled here on target level
            dependencies: [.product(name: "BaseTypeExtension", package: "BaseTypeExtension")]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SecondPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["SecondPackage"]
        ),
    ]
)

